# Can handle multiple errors using Nestjs' Exception Filter?

Tags: nestjs

Spring boot was able to handle various errors using @RestControllerAdvice. The code created by spring boot is as follows.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    // @valid에서 바인딩 에러가 발생
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
        log.error("handleMethodArgumentNotValidException ==> " + e);
        final ErrorResponse response = ErrorResponse.of(ErrorCode.WRONG_INPUT_VALUE, e.getBindingResult());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // 사용자 생성시 이메일이 중복된 경우
    @ExceptionHandler(DuplicateEmailException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleDuplicateEmailException(DuplicateEmailException e) {
        log.error("handleDuplicateEmailException ==> " + e);
        final ErrorResponse response = ErrorResponse.of(ErrorCode.DUPLICATE_EMAIL_VALUE);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    ...
}
```

Currently, I was looking for features similar to @RestControllerAdvice while using NestJs to handle errors, and I found out about ExceptionFilter. I wrote the code, but I had a question after writing it. If we process the error like this, we can only process errors related to HttPexception, right?

I want to handle other errors globally besides HttPexception. However, unlike Spring Boot's @RestControllerAdvice, ExceptionFilter does not seem to be able to handle many errors in a single class. Am I using it wrong?

```
@Catch()
export class ExceptionHandler implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
        const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
        const status = exception.getStatus();

        response.status(status).json({
            statusCode: status,
            message: exception.message,
            path: request.url
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass exception class to `@Catch()` decorator.
If you want to catch all http exceptions you can do

```js
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch(HttpException)
export class ExceptionHandler implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
        const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
        const status = exception.getStatus();

        response.status(status).json({
            statusCode: status,
            message: exception.message,
            path: request.url
        });
    }
}
```

This will catch all errors thrown when executing any route.

You can also pass a few exception classes to catch only particular exceptions.

```js
 @Catch(BadRequestException, UnauthorizedException)
```

You can read more at https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters